# How to remove an element of array in foreach loop?

Tags: perl

I want to loop through an array and check if some elements is equal to a specific condition . 
For example , I want to remove the element contains `"O"` , so I can do in this way ..

```
@Array = ("Apple","Orange","Banana");
for ($i=0 ; $i <= $#Array ; $i++) {
    if( index($Array[$i],"O") >= 0 ) {
        splice(@Array,$i,1);
    }
}
```

but if I want to use `foreach` loop to replace `for` loop , how do I do ? because in `foreach` loop , there is no index so I can't use `splice` , unless I set a variable to store it .

Comment: `for` and `foreach` is the exact same thing, they are aliases. It is the C-style syntax that makes a difference.

Comment: your code is buggy; if there are more than one elements in a row containing "O", only the odd ones will be removed.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you want to remove elements, the better tool is `grep`:

```
@array = grep { !/O/ } @array;
```

Technically, it is possible to do with a `for` loop, but you'd have to jump through some hoops to do it, or copy to another array:

```
my @result;
for (@array) {
    if (/O/) {
        push @result, $_;
    }
}
```

You should know that `for` and `foreach` are aliases, and they do exactly the same thing. It is the C-style syntax that you are thinking of:

```
for (@array) { print $_, "\n"; }        # perl style, with elements
for (my $x = 0; $x <= $#array; $x++) {  # C-style, with indexes
  print $array[$x], "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

BTW, you can still use a `foreach`-style `for` loop to process and remove elements — *without* having to build a whole new array...

Just work ***backwards*** from beginning-to-end:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

my @fruits = qw< Apple Orange Banana >;

for my $index ( reverse 0 .. $#fruits ) {
    my $item = $fruits[$index];

    if ( $item =~ /^O/ ) {
        # Do something...
        say "Removing #$index: $item";

        # Remove the current item... 
        splice @fruits => $index, 1;
    }
}
```

Or, in the spirit of TMTOWTDI:

```
say "Removing #$_: " . splice @fruits => $_, 1
  for grep $fruits[$_] =~ /^O/, reverse 0 .. $#fruits;
```

Answer (score 0):

In case your `for` loop does other things than just remove elements, you could do something like this:

```
@Array = ("Apple","Orange","Banana");
@del = ();
for my $i (0..$#Array) {
    # do your stuff
    unshift @del, $i if ($Array[$i] eq "Orange");
}
map { splice @Array, $_, 1 } @del;
```